# Error in loading Javascript in R with v8

Tags: javascript, r, v8

i want to run the javascript code at https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet#via-script-tag in R with the package V8. I create a new context, i load the first js with the "source", but the second js gives me an error:

```
> library("V8")
> sess=v8()
> sess$source("https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow-models/posenet@0.1/dist/posenet.min.js")
[1] "true"
> sess$source("https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.7/dist/tf.min.js")
Error in context_eval(join(src), private$context) : 
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

Are there alternatives working libraries? There is an alternative method to load the second js?